# How can I restrict access to my website using only my domain?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, digital-ocean

I have found a website which is serving my website with mydomain.com.otherdomain.com I want to restrict this.Please help.

This effects the SEO of the website.

Comment: Lucky If you please pardon me I would prefer not to disclose the real domain

Comment: whats the site that is serving your site>

Comment: planhe.com it is served as a sub domain to this domain.

Comment: you can blacklist the domain and/or IP of that domain on your server. Any request from that server will be blocked

Comment: it would be helpful if you can mention how?

Comment: do you have access to cpanel?

Comment: no I do not have a cpanel

Comment: ubuntu via command prompt

Comment: IPtables? should have that

Comment: please check your sites also : https://www.google.co.in/search?q=site%3Aplanhe.com

Comment: planhe.com is hosted on digital ocean. have them look into it

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/company/contact/#tab_abusetrigger

Comment: Did that but not helpful yet.Will update

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a lawyer, but there might be some legal options concerning trademarks or other things you might have on your site.

Technically it's basically impossible, there ae many ways that could be set up, and some of them are really hard to tell apart from legitimate traffic. And we would need to see what is happening before we can say something about what might work in the specific case.

Comment: Thanks Henrik but I feel technically speaking it should be possible at the networking layer at least.

Comment: As I said, that depend on how it's done, if they're just serving a frame that instructs the browser to load your site, there's no network traffic between you and them, and thus nothing to target in the networking layer.

Answer (score 0):

I want to post as a record for someone who faces this issue.

Solution is : in the .htaccess remove the generic redirect and add an domain specific redirect it will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is a [302 hijack](http://m.dummies.com/how-to/content/prevent-someone-from-hijacking-your-web-sites-sear.html). You will have to contact the site and the site's hosting company to report the issue. Unfortunately there is nothing more you can do.